# Filling data in Pandas Series with help of a function

Tags: pandas, function, apply

I want to fill values of a column on a certain condition, as in the example in the image:

[image]

What's the reason for the TypeError? How can I go about it?

Comment: Since you are using `Series.apply` your function should take a value as the argument and return _something_. Then once the function is a proper method you would do `df.C.apply(fill_c)` without calling fill_c with ()

Comment: pls provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and have a look on [why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20can't%20be%20searched,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you are using `df.apply()` correctly. Remember to post the code as text next time. Here is a working example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [x for x in range (5,11)], 'B':[np.nan, np.nan, 5,11,4,np.nan]})

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: '' if pd.isna(row['B']) else row['A'], axis=1)

df
```

**Output:**

```py
    A     B  C
0   5   NaN
1   6   NaN
2   7   5.0  7
3   8  11.0  8
4   9   4.0  9
5  10   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you it is very helpful. Is there a way to solve the same problem with series.apply, instead of df.apply. What is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: @Rockoos You can have a look at the different documentation for  [`series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). The difference is that `series.apply` accesses one column (series) and applies a function over the cell values, and `df.apply` can access all columns in a dataframe.

In this case I do not see as to why you would use `series.apply`. This is because you are creating a new column based on several columns in a dataframe.